# How to load balancing with nginx using uwsgi-socket

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, nginx-config

I am using socket file for accessing my application with nginx.
my application consist of three server listening on 8080, 8081, 8082.
server configuration under /etc/nginx/sites-available/config-file is below

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name my-server-one;
    location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/server_one.sock;
    }


server {
    listen 8081 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name my-server-two;
    location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/server_two.sock;
    }

server {
    listen 8082 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name my-server-two;
    location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/server_three.sock;
    }
```

my question is how can i apply load balance with upstream?
like below upstream container

```
upstream myserver {
    server localhost:8080;
    server localhost:8081;
    server localhost:8082;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks i found the solution finally and want to share

for setting up nginx load balancer i added the .sock file in upstream and pass the upstream to uwsgi_pass

[nginx load balancer with socket](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html)

```
upstream myserver {
   server unix:///tmp/server_one.sock;
   server unix:///tmp/server_two.sock;
   server unix:///tmp/server_three.sock;
}
```

the /etc.nginx/sites-available/nginx-config files are below

```
server {
   listen 8080 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   root /var/www/html;
   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   server_name my-server-one;
   location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass myserver;
}

server {
   listen 8081 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   root /var/www/html;
   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   server_name my-server-two;
   location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass myserver;
}

server {
   listen 8082 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   root /var/www/html;
   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   server_name my-server-two;
   location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass myserver;
}
```